# Continuous Time Markov Chain - find matrix

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

Could someone please point me in the right direction for solving this problem? I am new to Markov chain theory and am confused about how to start, thanks.

Consider a Poisson process $\{N(t): t\geq 0\}$ with parameter $\lambda$, which can be interpreted as a continuous-time Markov chain. Find the corresponding matrix $P(t)$.

Comment: The only transitions are jumps of magnitude $+1$ and the distribution of jump times is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. So $P$ is an upper-triangular matrix. See these notes for a derivation: https://cs.nyu.edu/mishra/COURSES/09.HPGP/scribe3

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson process $N(t)$ has infinitesimal generator
$$
Q_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\lambda,& j=i+1\\
-\lambda,& j=i\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
We can show by induction that 
$$
Q_{ij}^{(n)} = \begin{cases}
\binom n{j-i} \lambda^n (-1)^{n-(j-i)},& 0\leqslant j-i\leqslant n\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The transition probabilities are given by $P(t) = e^{tQ}$, and so for each pair of nonnegative integers $j\geqslant i$ we have
\begin{align}
P_{ij}(t) &= \sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}Q_{ij}^{(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}\binom n{j-i} \lambda^n (-1)^{n-(j-i)}\\
&=\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^{j-i}}{(j-i)!}\lambda^{j-i}\frac{t^{n-(j-i)}}{(n-(j-i))!}(-\lambda)^{n-(j-i)}\\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!}\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda t)^{n-(j-i)}}{(n-(j-i))!}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda t)^k}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
As expected, the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ (with $j\geqslant i$) in $(0,t]$ is the probability of there being $j-i$ arrivals in $(0,t]$.